# DLL Timer Best Practice

Tags: c#, dll

I have a DLL that polls a GSM modem.

When the modem receives a SMS, the DLL preprocesses the content and  sends it off to the Application via an interrupt.
The application processes the data and sends back the result to the DLL, which passes it on the sender via SMS.
If the system has two modems then the application has two instantiations of the dll.

```
 IMyModem modem1 = new MyModem(...);
 IMyModem modem2 = new MyModem(...);
```

I am thinking that there are two independent instantiations of the Dll in memory therefore I only need one System.Timers.Timer in the DLL. i.e. two separate copies of it will be elapsing independently of each other.

The Application UI can also effect the modems. (Results, Request isolation,test tx, etc).

To control the interaction between UI requests and the polling I have two static Mutex's in the DLL, one for each modem. The timer elapsed handler and other routines knows which modem they are dealing with as they were told during instantiation. So they know which Mutex to WaitOne() on.

I have tested, and while it seems to work ok, I am concerned that there may be a weakness in the design that won't show up until it goes under production load.
I would appreciate 'The Panel's' thoughts on the matter.

Comment: This description is probably too vague for anybody to be able to judge your design.

Comment: Just looking for affirmation (or not) of underlying design assumptions. e.g. Yep, two distinct timer instances in memory or Noooo, both instances share same timer etc.

Comment: There should not be two instances of the same DLL loaded. Maybe two references, but in one application space, you should only need one reference. OK, two instances of your MyModem object, one for each modem. Assuming the timer object is a non-static member of MyModem, you'll have two separate timers, operating (running/expiring) independently of each other.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like it will work OK.